# Indefinite integral of fraction?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to integrate $$\int\frac{1}{x^{14}+1}dx$$
I've tried to use partial fraction decomposition but it doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure no bounds?

Comment: @jamie yep, I need to find indefinite integral of this

Comment: the indefinite integral doesn't have a closed form, however if you are integrating in the whole $\mathbb{R}$ then you can use the residue theorem to find a closed form for it value

Comment: @Masacroso So, any "simple" methods (like from algebra) will not work?

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is the sum of a geometric series with common ratio $-x^{14}$, so your integral equals

$$\int 1 - x^{14} + x^{28} - x^{42} + \cdots \; dx $$

$$= x - \frac{x^{15}}{15} + \frac{x^{29}}{29} - \cdots.$$

That's probably as good as you're going to do.  (Plus constant.)